# Ошибка при компиляции [Error] expected primary-expression before '||' token

Tags: c++

код

```
#include "iostream"
#include"math.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, s, t, u, p, p1, p2;
    s != 0;
    t != 0;
    cout << "Vvedite a,b,c,d,s,t,u  " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> s >> t >> u;
    p1 = s*a + t*b + u;
    p2 = s*c + t*d + u;
    if (p1>0&&p2>0) || (p1<0&&p2<0);
    cout << "Nalezat odniy ploschini" << endl; 
    return 0;
    if (p1<0&&p2>0) || (p1>0&&p2<0);
    cout << "Nalezat riznim ploschinam" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И что такое

```
if (p1 > 0 && p2 > 0) || (p1 < 0 && p2 < 0);
```

Инструкция `if` имеет вид

```
if ( условие )  { что-то-там } [else { что-то-там-еще }]
```

У вас одно условие **без** скобок и без инструкций для выполнения... По сути -

```
if условие
```

Вот как должен выглядеть ваш код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, s, t, u, p, p1, p2;
    s != 0;
    t != 0;
    cout << "Vvedite a,b,c,d,s,t,u " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> s >> t >> u;
    p1 = sa + tb + u;
    p2 = sc + td + u;

    if ((p1 > 0 && p2 > 0) || (p1 < 0 && p2 < 0))
    {
        cout << "Nalezat odniy ploschini" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if ((p1 < 0 && p2 > 0) || (p1 > 0 && p2 < 0))
    {
        cout << "Nalezat riznim ploschinam" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Кстати, обратите внимание на угловые скобки `<>` в директивах `#include`!

Answer (score 0):

1. Логическое выражение в `if` должно быть в круглых скобках.
2. Всё что должно быть внутри условия нужно размещать внутри фигурных скобок

   ```
   if ((p1>0&&p2>0) || (p1<0&&p2<0)){
     cout << "Nalezat odniy ploschini" << endl; 
     return 0;
   }
   ```